# unable to delete random array elements on onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have an array and displaying its content wrapped up in a P tag on the body, now how do I delete the element when I click on the specific element.

JS:

```
var arr = [10, 20, 30];

var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 demo.innerHTML += `<p class="tag">${arr[i]} </p>`;
 }

 var pTag = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
 for( var j = 0; j < pTag.length; j++) {
  pTag[j].onclick = function() {
    arr.splice(pTag[j], 1);

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array methods instead - don't use `var` with asynchronous code, since it gets hoisted and has function scope instead of block scope.

```js
const arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
arr.forEach(num => {
  const p = demo.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
  p.textContent = num;
  p.addEventListener('click', () => {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(num), 1);
    p.remove();
    console.log('now have ' + JSON.stringify(arr));
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

I'd recommend avoiding `getElementsByClassName`. The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying you code, I have came up with this:

```js
var arr = [10, 20, 30];

var demo = document.getElementById('demo');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  demo.innerHTML += `<p class="tag">${arr[i]} </p>`;
}

var pTag = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
for (var j = 0; j < pTag.length; j++) {
  pTag[j].onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.innerText);
    this.remove();
    var num = parseInt(this.innerText);
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(num), 1);
    console.log(arr)
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you could do.

```js
var arr = [10, 20, 30];

var demo = document.querySelector('#demo');
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  demo.innerHTML += `<p class="tag">${arr[i]} </p>`;
}

demo.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.remove();
});
```

```html
<div id='demo'>
</div>
```